# CFTimeInterval as Float

Tags: types, swift

I'm making a game using swift, and I need to make use of Delta Time, but it's a CFTimeInterval (Double), and ideally I need it to be a float value so I can use it in my other code.

I'm guessing it's easy, I just can't get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean. Do you want to pass `CFTimeInterval` a float or make it into a float? Either way it should be one of these:

```
let someFloat: Float = 2.0;

// passing it a float
let someInterval = CFTimeInterval(someFloat)

// creating a float with it
let someOtherFloat = Float(someInterval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to Float() I think:

```
var newValue = Float(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())
println("Float value: \(newValue)")
```